# エクセルに張った株探と四季報へのリンクを企業コードごとに更新したい

Tags: excel

エクセル(Windows11)で株価情報の管理をしています。各シートが各企業の情報を持つようにしています。それらのシートをまとめるためにIndexシートを作成しブックの一枚目においています。Indexシートでは縦軸に企業名が各企業のシートタブから入力されその企業名から企業コード、決算月等の情報を同じく参照し反映させています。さらにKabutan、四季報そしてTradingview等のWeb情報サービスのその企業のページを別途開くようにハイパーリンクを入力しました。ハイパーリンクはうまく機能していますが、Web情報サービスは各企業ごとに企業コードを変えて入力しなければならないため一企業ごとに手作業となってしいます。そこのところを自動化できないかという相談です。

例えば四季報のページへのリンクはこのようになるのですが、`=HYPERLINK("https://shikiho.jp/stocks/7373/","四季報")` この中の7373の部分が企業コードとなっていてそこを変えることで他の企業のページへ変わります。Indexには50から100社がリストアップされていますので手作業となるとすべてのリンクを変更するわけですが、既に同じシートに企業コードのリストがあるのでそれを参照してリンクの中の企業コードの部分だけを変更する関数の使い方がありましたらご教授ください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LibreOffice Calc で動作確認を行いました。

一度にまとめるような記述はうまくいかなかったので少し冗長ですが、以下の手順で実現可能かと思います。

証券コードが `A1` に入力されているとして、参照と文字列の結合を組み合わせて以下のように URL を生成できます。

| A1 | A2 (式) | A2 (結果) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7373 | `="https://shikiho.jp/stocks/" & A1` | https://shikiho.jp/stocks/7373 |

次に、A2 の結果の URL を利用して `HYPERLINK` を設定します。

| A1 | A3 (式) | A3 (結果) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7373 | `=HYPERLINK(A2, "四季報")` | 四季報 |

Comment: KabutanとTradingviewでも確認できました。